# Split in View asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, split

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SonerSevincComEntities context = new SonerSevincComEntities();

        var Konular = context.Konu.ToList();
        return View(Konular);
    }
```

VİEW:

```
                 <div class="primary">

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <h2>
                        <a href="Subject?SubjectId=
                         @Html.DisplayFor(model =>   item.Id)">
                         @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Baslik)</a>
                        </h2>

                        <p class="post-info">
                            <a href="Subject?Tag=
                           @Html.DisplayFor(model =>item.Etiket)">
                           @item.Etiket.Split(',').ToString()</a>
                        </p>

                        <div class="image-section">
                            <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Resim)" 
                             alt="image post" height="206" width="498" />
                        </div>

                        <p>
                       <a class="more" href="Subject?SubjectId==
                       @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Id)">Devamı &raquo;</a>
                        </p>           
                    }
                </div>
```

I want to split under side for (',')

```
@item.Etiket.Split(',').ToString()
```

When i run program , i see this code..

**System.String[]** in stead of Etiket

I tried to solve this with foreach Etiket.Split but id did not work .

How can i solve this problem in View?

Comment: Do u know Split returns array?? Which value u need?

Comment: all values inside Etiket 
As instance Economy,Finance
I want them 
1-Economy
2-Finance
like this apart apart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx): Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this string that are delimited by elements of a specified string array.

So what you are getting is correct output as per code.

You can try to display first element of substring

```
@item.Etiket.Split(',')[0]
```

Comment: `String.ToString()` is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

```
                       <a href="Subject?Tag=
                       @Html.DisplayFor(model =>item.Etiket)">
                       @item.Etiket.Split(',').ToString()</a>
```

it should be like following as you said in your comment

```
                       <a href="Subject?Tag=
                       @Html.DisplayFor(model =>item.Etiket)">
                      @foreach(var x in item.Etiket.Split(','))
                           {
                              @x
                       } 
                       </a>
```

Comment: at the time of first iteration @x is the 1st item, then 2nd ...... 3rd ...........